# Как пишется "не()к()спеху"?

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу запомнить: как пишется "не()к()спеху"? По идее, это наречие и должно писаться слитно. Или нет?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раздельно. Да, это наречие, но ведь далеко не все наречия пишутся слитно. Единого правила нет, определяется историческими причинами, иногда даже просто традицией.

В данном случае, я думаю, что никакой мотивации для слитного написания нет и быть не может, сочетание "к спеху" даже не приобрело законченного самостоятельного значения.

Comment: Выражение *к спеху* в 19 веке употреблялось весьма широко : 
> Н. В. Гоголь. Письма 1836-1841 гг. (1836-1841) Никак не хочется заниматься тем, **что нужно к спеху**, а всё бы хотелось заняться тем, **что не к спеху.**

[Нацкорпус](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&kwsz=5&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=&env=fol1&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&text=lexform&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA+%F1%EF%E5%F5%F3)

Comment: Ну и?
      
.


.

Comment: Что за спех? Давайте без спеха...

Answer (score 3):

Не к чему? - к спеху - наречное выражение, состоящее из существительного с предлогом. Сейчас это разговорный фразеологизм,слово СПЕХ употребляется редко, но в 19 веке употреблялось часто:◆ Начали гневно: «Как же это вы, сударь! Чего вы смотрите? нужная бумага, нужно к спеху, а вы ее портите. И как же вы это». Ф. М. Достоевский, «Бедные люди», 1846 г. (цитата из Нацкорпуса ).У В.В.Вересаева есть повесть "К спеху".         http://frazeologiya.ru/fraza/speh.htm

Comment: Людмила, это все в той или иной мере объясняет раздельное написание "НЕ". А вот автор вопроса предполагает возможность слитного написания "кспеху". Это-то есть возможность как-то объяснить креме как отсылкой в словарь или авторитетным источникам?

Comment: Словообразование наречий ещё не завершено. Если это окончательно наречие и отвечает на вопросы ТОЛЬКО наречия-Где? Куда?когда?откуда?почему?зачем? и как?, то пишется слитно. Если возможно поставить вопрос существительного, значит, это существительное и с предлогом пишется раздельно. Поэтому я и привела вопрос-К ЧЕМУ? Значит, это сущ. с предлогом-раздельно.Говорил Как?-вразнобой (во что? не скажешь)носил рубаху как?-навыпуск, но пошёл куда? на что?-на выпуск к брату, посмотрел на что? на выпуск продукции.Ехал как? навстречу-наречие, пошёл куда? на что? на встречу с братом - сущ. с предлогом.